# Vimeo embed video is not fullscreening on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, vimeo

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=256247), there is a known issue fullscreening embedded Vimeo video on Crome in portfolio items.

With several debugging attemps, I found the needed workaround.

While Wordpress places the iframe under a div with class names `large-6 columns project-content animated fadeInRightBig` in portfolio item:

```
<div class="large-6 columns"></div>
<div class="large-6 columns project-content animated fadeInRightBig">
    <p>
        <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/96460937" width="625" height="352" frameborder="0" title="Bardaki Ruh 3.bölüm" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

If I place the node INBETWEEN the divs with class names `large-6 columns` AND `large-6 columns project-content animated fadeInRightBig`:

```
<div class="large-6 columns"></div>
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/96460937" width="625" height="352" frameborder="0" title="Bardaki Ruh 3.bölüm" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<div class="large-6 columns project-content animated fadeInRightBig">
```

the issue resolves.

The only way I can think of is to use JS but I couldn't make it. I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: Atleast paste the code from your browser source and put make a nice [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Exactly, to replicate the issue, one has to write down the code in that image... personally, I don't feel like doing it... Also, can you show the JS you already attempted?

Comment: Something like that `$('.project-content > p > iframe').each(function() {$(this).parent().before(this);})`
Here is the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9CDUr/1/

Comment: this is the solution that I come so far: http://jsfiddle.net/9CDUr/3/